# Confusing TypeError

Tags: python, tkinter, self, typeerror

I have a small Python program that should react to pushing the up button by running an appropriate method. But instead of doing this, it gives me a confusing error...

```
from tkinter import *
class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.left = 0
        self.right = 0
        widget = Label(master, text='Hello bind world')
        widget.config(bg='red')            
        widget.config(height=5, width=20)                  
        widget.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        widget.bind('<Up>',self.incSpeed)   
        widget.focus()
    def incSpeed(self):
        print("Test")

root = Tk() 
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

And the error is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1402, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: incSpeed() takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given)
```

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `incSpeed` method should take an extra argument; yours only takes `self` but it is passed an [event argument](http://docs.python.org/library/tkinter.html#bindings-and-events) as well.

Update your function signature to accept it:

```
def incSpeed(self, event):
    print("Test")
```