# Python method giving TypeError takes exactly 9 arguments (8 given)

Tags: python, methods, arguments, typeerror, trace

I am running into a TypeError about # of parameters when calling a Python method (2.7.2). Most of the similar questions that I have found online occur when people forget that "self" is also a parameter ([sample SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507278/confusing-typeerror)). Or, when someone forgets to concatenate arguments (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17556928/python-typeerror-one-argument-six-given)).

I am not sure if this is also a "self" issue, but it seems to be different. I am basically getting an error that I don't have **enough** arguments, even though I count enough. In my trace:

```
-> message += XMLProcessor(zf, root, filepath, tag_type, display_name, containers, depth, message, username)
(Pdb) n
TypeError: 'XMLProcessor() takes exactly 9 arguments (8 given)'
```

Now, I have counted this multiple times, and I swear there are 9 arguments. But I may be mistaken or missing something critical? This method is not part of a class, so I would assume "self" is not an issue...I feel like I am missing a fundamental understanding of something, but not sure what.

```
########## Function: XMLProcessor #################
# This does the work of examining the XML and traversing it.
####################################################
def XMLProcessor(zf, root, filepath, tag_type, display_name, containers, depth, message, username):
```

Could anyone please shed some light on why 9 != 9 in this case?

Thanks!

---

### UPDATE #1

So I have no idea what this means, but running the code that Martijn provided in my debugger:

```
(Pdb) import inspect, dis;
(Pdb) dis.dis(inspect.currentframe().f_code)
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (dis)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (dis)
              6 LOAD_NAME                1 (inspect)
              9 LOAD_ATTR                2 (currentframe)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             15 LOAD_ATTR                3 (f_code)
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             21 PRINT_EXPR          
             22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             25 RETURN_VALUE        
(Pdb)
```

---

### Update #2

Still trying to get up to speed on dis, but I find it kind of ironic that my code tries to ignore exactly 9 arguments. On a side-note, I have cleared out my *.pyc files and rerun my code...no help:

```
(Pdb) XMLProcessor(zf, root, filepath, tag_type, display_name, containers, depth, message, username)
*** TypeError: XMLProcessor() takes exactly 9 arguments (8 given)
(Pdb) XMLProcessor(zf, root, filepath, tag_type, display_name, containers, depth, message, username, '')
*** TypeError: XMLProcessor() takes exactly 9 arguments (10 given)
```

---

### Solved!

As I noted in the comments, this wound up being not related to stale bytecodes (though that sounds like something I will definitely have to investigate in the future), but more coder oversight. I am modifying someone else's legacy code, and **it turns out that XMLProcessor is a recursive method. And I didn't modify the internal, recursive method call for the new argument.** So the "8" argument error was actually fired on the internal call, whereas the "10" argument error in Update #2 was fired on the external call. Since I had set my trace() before the external call, to me both errors looked the same--as if they were coming from my external call...Gah!!! Thanks everyone for your help--I need to work on my debugging techniques, and I learned some useful tricks from this.

Comment: Did you restart your process? Is there a possibility of stale bytecode being loaded? The source code you see is not necessarily what Python is running; the byte code is executed with pointers to specific line numbers in the source, and if the source code *changed* in the meantime you'll get to see code that *differs* from what is running.

Comment: As Martijn Pieters said, the bytecode might be stale. Your code works for me.

Comment: When you run into this problem in the debugger, can you run `import inspect, dis; dis.dis(inspect.currentframe().f_code)` and paste the output here? That'll show the *actual bytecode* being run, as a disassembly.

Comment: Hi Martijn, DeadChex, thanks for your comments. I just re-saved my code, restarted my process (still failed), and then rebooted my dev machine, but the problem persists. I will try the commands that Martijn just posted.

Comment: @DeadChex, thanks for confirming that the code itself is good...that helps me at least focus my troubleshooting. I was worried I missed something basic.

Comment: Can someone else also confirm the code given works? I'm just passing `None` as all the argument values... confirm someone please?

Comment: I can self-confirm, I guess. Passing None for all the arguments also gets me past the TypeError. It seems like one of my arguments (root) is the problem-child. It is an XML etree--not sure why I can't pass it around but will investigate. Thanks for getting me pointed in the right direction!

Comment: What are the types of the other arguments?

Comment: So turns out it was a really stupid error on my part, nothing to do with argument types. I'm modifying legacy code, and XMLProcessor is a recursive function--I missed updating the recursive method call inside the method. So the original "8" error was on the internal call, but the "10" error I posted in Update #2 was on the external call. Since my trace was running outside of the method, to me both errors looked the same! Stupid...I will be adding some debugging tricks to my toolbag, based on this. Thanks, everyone!

Comment: This is a pretty useful resource as the solution was non-trivial. Please post your self-answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, I'm posting the solution here to make it more obvious.

---

TLDR

---

The legacy method (`XMLProcessor`) was recursive, and the `TypeError` was being triggered on the recursive call in the method definition. I was tracing outside of the method and didn't realize that.

---

Original post

---

Solved!

As I noted in the comments, this wound up being not related to stale bytecodes (though that sounds like something I will definitely have to investigate in the future), but more coder oversight. I am modifying someone else's legacy code, and it turns out that XMLProcessor is a recursive method. And I didn't modify the internal, recursive method call for the new argument. So the "8" argument error was actually fired on the internal call, whereas the "10" argument error in Update #2 was fired on the external call. Since I had set my trace() before the external call, to me both errors looked the same--as if they were coming from my external call...Gah!!! Thanks everyone for your help--I need to work on my debugging techniques, and I learned some useful tricks from this.